# Media em listas com dicionarios

Tags: python

Eu tenho 2 listas de dicionarios e  1 dicionario , como por exemplo as seguintes :

```
lista1 = [
    {'Idade': '8',  'Especie': 'Gato',      'Nome do Animal': 'Felix'},
    {'Idade': '57', 'Especie': 'Tartaruga', 'Nome do Animal': 'Michelangelo'},
    {'Idade': '12', 'Especie': 'Cao',       'Nome do Animal': 'Rantanplian'},
    {'Idade': '2',  'Especie': 'Peixe',     'Nome do Animal': 'Nemo'},
    {'Idade': '45', 'Especie': 'Tartaruga', 'Nome do Animal': 'Leonardo'},
    {'Idade': '9',  'Especie': 'Cao',       'Nome do Animal': 'Milo'},
    {'Idade': '57', 'Especie': 'Tartaruga', 'Nome do Animal': 'Raphael'},
    {'Idade': '4',  'Especie': 'Peixe',     'Nome do Animal': 'Dory'} ]

lista2 = [
    {'Nome do Dono ': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Michelangelo'},
    {'Nome do Dono ': 'Eva', 'Nome do Animal': 'Dory'},
    {'Nome do Dono ': 'Ada', 'Nome do Animal': 'Rantanplan'},
    {'Nome do Dono ': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Leonardo'},
    {'Nome do Dono ': 'Eva', 'Nome do Animal': 'Felix'},
    {'Nome do Dono ': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Raphael'},
    {'Nome do Dono ': 'Eva', 'Nome do Animal': 'Nemo'} ]



dicionario3 ={
 'Eva': ['Dory', 'Felix', 'Nemo'],
 'Ana': ['Michelangelo', 'Leonardo', 'Raphael'],
 'Ada': ['Rantanplan']}
```

E  o que pretendo fazer é transformar o dicionario 3 numa lista de dicionarios , onde em vez dos nomes dos animais estará a média de idade desses animais por dono e arredondar esses valores " para cima ", por exemplo no caso da Eva o valor da 4,6 , logo terá de aparecer 5 em vez de 4. Ja tentei varias coisas e nao obtive resultado , alguem pode ajudar ?

O que pretendo é isto :

```
[{'Ana':'53','Eva':'5','Ada':'12'}]
```

A minha primeira duvida é como ir buscar so os nomes dos animais do dicionario3

Comment: Acho que ficaria mais claro se você escrevesse qual é o resultado esperado para a entrada que você usou de exemplo. Você poderia fazer isso? E quais coisas você já tentou que não funcionaram? Em geral fica mais fácil escrever uma boa resposta se soubermos o que você já tentou e quais são as dificuldades que você encontrou.

Comment: Ja editei a pergunta @hugomg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito parecido com a sua pergunta anterior:

```
from collections import defaultdict

resultado = defaultdict(list)
media_idades = defaultdict(list)

animais = [
    {'Idade': '8', 'Especie': 'Gato', 'Nome do Animal': 'Felix'},
    {'Idade': '57', 'Especie': 'Tartaruga', 'Nome do Animal': 'Michelangelo'},
    {'Idade': '12', 'Especie': 'Cao', 'Nome do Animal': 'Rantanplian'},
    {'Idade': '2', 'Especie': 'Peixe', 'Nome do Animal': 'Nemo'},
    {'Idade': '45', 'Especie': 'Tartaruga', 'Nome do Animal': 'Leonardo'},
    {'Idade': '9', 'Especie': 'Cao', 'Nome do Animal': 'Milo'},
    {'Idade': '57', 'Especie': 'Tartaruga', 'Nome do Animal': 'Raphael'},
    {'Idade': '4', 'Especie': 'Peixe', 'Nome do Animal': 'Dory'}]

donos = [
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Michelangelo'},
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Eva', 'Nome do Animal': 'Dory'},
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Rantanplian'},
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Leonardo'},
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Eva', 'Nome do Animal': 'Felix'},
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Ana', 'Nome do Animal': 'Raphael'},
    {'Nome do Dono': 'Eva', 'Nome do Animal': 'Nemo'}]

for dono in donos:
    for animal in animais:
        if dono['Nome do Animal'] == animal['Nome do Animal']:
            resultado[dono['Nome do Dono']].append(
                int(animal['Idade'])
            )

# Modificando o  defaultdict para um dicionário normal:
resultado = dict(resultado)

for key, values in resultado.items():
    media_idades[key].append(sum(values)/len(values))


# Modificando o  defaultdict para um dicionário normal:
media_idades = dict(media_idades)

print(media_idades)
```

Answer (score 2):

Fiz o código em AngularJS para você acompanhar a lógica.

Está aqui: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thavia/q04jw960/)

```
angular.module('dicionario', [])

.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.lista1 = [{
    'idade': 8,
    'especie': 'Gato',
    'nome': 'Felix'
  }, {
    'idade': 57,
    'especie': 'Tartaruga',
    'nome': 'Michelangelo'
  }, {
    'idade': 12,
    'especie': 'Cao',
    'nome': 'Rantanplan'
  }, {
    'idade': 2,
    'especie': 'Peixe',
    'nome': 'Nemo'
  }, {
    'idade': 45,
    'especie': 'Tartaruga',
    'nome': 'Leonardo'
  }, {
    'idade': 9,
    'especie': 'Cao',
    'nome': 'Milo'
  }, {
    'idade': 57,
    'especie': 'Tartaruga',
    'nome': 'Raphael'
  }, {
    'idade': 4,
    'especie': 'Peixe',
    'nome': 'Dory'
  }];

  $scope.lista2 = [{
    'dono': 'Ana',
    'nome': 'Michelangelo'
  }, {
    'dono': 'Eva',
    'nome': 'Dory'
  }, {
    'dono': 'Ada',
    'nome': 'Rantanplan'
  }, {
    'dono': 'Ana',
    'nome': 'Leonardo'
  }, {
    'dono': 'Eva',
    'nome': 'Felix'
  }, {
    'dono': 'Ana',
    'nome': 'Raphael'
  }, {
    'dono': 'Ana',
    'nome': 'Milo'
  }, {
    'dono': 'Eva',
    'nome': 'Nemo'
  }];

  $scope.especies = [];
  $scope.donos = [];
  $scope.media = [];
  $scope.mediadono = [];

  angular.forEach($scope.lista1, function(lista1) {
    $scope.especies.push(lista1.especie);


    angular.forEach($scope.lista2, function(lista2) {
      if (lista1.nome == lista2.nome){
        lista1.dono = lista2.dono;

      }


    });

  });

    angular.forEach($scope.lista2, function(lista2) {
    $scope.donos.push(lista2.dono);
  });

  jQuery.unique($scope.especies); //tira os duplicados
  jQuery.unique($scope.donos);

  angular.forEach($scope.especies, function(esp) {
    var somarIdade = 0;
    var contarIdades = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.lista1, function(lista1) {

      if (esp == lista1.especie) {
        contarIdades++;
        somarIdade = somarIdade + lista1.idade;
      }
    });

    $scope.media.push({
      media: somarIdade / contarIdades,
      especie: esp
    });
  });

    angular.forEach($scope.donos, function(dono) {
    var somarIdade = 0;
    var contarIdades = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.lista1, function(lista1) {

      if (dono == lista1.dono) {
        contarIdades++;
        somarIdade = somarIdade + lista1.idade;
      }
    });

    $scope.mediadono.push({
      media: somarIdade / contarIdades,
      dono: dono
    });
  });



  angular.forEach($scope.lista1, function(lista1) {

angular.forEach($scope.media, function(valor) {

      if (lista1.especie == valor.especie) {
        lista1.media = valor.media;

      }

    });

        angular.forEach($scope.mediadono, function(valor) {

      if (lista1.dono == valor.dono) {
        lista1.mediadono = valor.media;

      }

    });

  });

});


<body ng-app='dicionario'>
  <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Espécie</th>
          <th>Nome</th>
          <th>Idade</th>
          <th>Dono</th>
          <th>Media por Animal</th>
           <th>Media por Dono</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat='ax in lista1'>
          <td>{{ax.especie}}</td>
          <td>{{ax.nome}}</td>
          <td>{{ax.idade}}</td>
          <td>{{ax.dono}}</td>
          <td>{{ax.media |number:2}}</td>
          <td>{{ax.mediadono |number:2}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```